# How do I create columns in a geom_col chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

So I am trying to use the following code to create a column chart that has 2 columns, best frequency and high frequency, imposed onto each other for each species, except I can't get the fill function to only fill in the smaller variable, it instead creates a color chart for the larger one.

Below is the code I am using, the first image is my result, the second is something along the lines of what I want. I am using ggplot, ggthemes and forcats as packages. Any help would greatly be appreciated, thank you!

```
ggplot(data = penta_calcs, mapping = aes(x = Best_frequency_of_hearing_kHz + High_frequency_of_hearing_limit_kHz, y = fct_reorder(Species, Clade), fill = High_frequency_of_hearing_limit_kHz)) + geom_col() + labs(title = "Best frequency of hearing in non-avian dinosaurs", x = "Hearing frequency (kHz)", y = " ") + scale_color_colorblind()
```

[Result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAoYA.png)

[Result I want along the lines of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY3FH.png)

Comment: It 's easier to help you if you provide some sample data. You can read this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, if you provide a sample of your data is easier. However, I can imagine that the solution is probably move from wide to long data. I can adjust the answer once you provide the data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  class = letters[1:5],
  high_frequency = sample(1:10, 5, replace = T),
  best_frequency = sample(1:10, 5, replace = T),
)

# Transform data from wide to long before plotting

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-class) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does your data look like the one I created?